# Sorting a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
c2=[]
row1=[1,22,53]
row2=[14,25,46]
row3=[7,8,9]

c2.append(row2)
c2.append(row1)
c2.append(row3)
```

`c2` is now:

```
[[14, 25, 46], [1, 22, 53], [7, 8, 9]]
```

how do i sort `c2` in such a way that for example:

```
for row in c2:

sort on row[2]
```

the result would be:

```
[[7,8,9],[14,25,46],[1,22,53]]
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific as to how exactly you want your stuff sorted. I see the order of the elements in the inner lists stays the same, but the order of the lists themselves changes. Explain your logic.

Comment: im sorry, i had a mistake in the data, check it now

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[The `key` argument to `sort`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element.  So we can create a simple `lambda` that returns the last element from each row to be used in the sort:

```
c2.sort(key = lambda row: row[2])
```

[A `lambda` is a simple anonymous function.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms)  It's handy when you want to create a simple single use function like this.  The equivalent code not using a `lambda` would be:

```
def sort_key(row):
    return row[2]

c2.sort(key = sort_key)
```

If you want to sort on more entries, just make the `key` function return a tuple containing the values you wish to sort on in order of importance.  For example:

```
c2.sort(key = lambda row: (row[2],row[1]))
```

or:

```
c2.sort(key = lambda row: (row[2],row[1],row[0]))
```

Comment: @I__: It's used to define quick inline functions.  http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk

Comment: thank you! the other question is how do i first sort by row[2] and within that set by row[1]

Comment: You could also do something like `import operator; c2.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))` or `c2.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2, 1))` or `c2.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2, 1, 0))`. It's apparently a fair bit faster than using a lambda expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import operator
>>> c2 = [[14, 25, 46], [1, 22, 53], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> c2.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
>>> c2
[[7, 8, 9], [14, 25, 46], [1, 22, 53]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, your desired example seems to indicate that you want to sort by the last index in the list, which could be done with this:

```
sorted_c2 = sorted(c2, lambda l1, l2: l1[-1] - l2[-1])
```

Comment: the other question is how do i first sort by row[2] and within that set by row[1]

Comment: mipadi, im sorry can u explain your answer, it seems very complicated

Comment: Both are fine.  mipdadi is using an alternative option to me.  Instead of specifying a `key` function which returns a single value to sort on, he's using a `sort` function which takes two values, compares then and returns an appropriate value.  I'd argue that my option is easier though. :-)

Comment: great! then he can help me sort on two elements

Comment: It should be noted too that whenever you can sort with the `key` option, you should. It will in general be faster than the pure comparison-based sort.

Comment: the `cmp` argument of sort is deprecated in Python2 and has been removed from Python3. You should use the `key` argument instead as it is more efficient