# Python Sorting Lists in Lists

Tags: python, list

Given: `lst = [['John',3],['Blake',4],['Ted',3]]`

Result: `lst = [['John',3],['Ted',3],['Blake',4]]`

I'm looking for a way to sort lists in lists first numerically then alphabetically without the use of the "itemgetter" syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you insist:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the argument `key` from the built-in `sorted` function.

In this `key` argument, you pass a function with one parameter, that returns something that will be sorted instead of sorting the list by its elements.

```
def my_func(elem):
    # return a tuple (second element, first element)
    return (elem[1], elem[0])

>>> lst = [['John',3],['Blake',4],['Ted',3]]
>>> sorted(lst, key=my_func)
[['John', 3], ['Ted', 3], ['Blake', 4]]
```

Or even shorter:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
[['John', 3], ['Ted', 3], ['Blake', 4]]
```

In both ways, you sort first numerically, then alphabetically.

Comment: I think Python suggest using `sorted()` before `.sort()` http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics

Answer (score 2):

I think this may have been asked before in the following question:

[Sorting a list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398589/sorting-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Here is the explanation given by Dave Webb:

[The `key` argument to `sort`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element.  So we can create a simple `lambda` that returns the last element from each row to be used in the sort:

```
c2.sort(key = lambda row: row[2])
```

[A `lambda` is a simple anonymous function.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms)  It's handy when you want to create a simple single use function like this.  The equivalent code not using a `lambda` would be:

```
def sort_key(row):
    return row[2]

c2.sort(key = sort_key)
```

If you want to sort on more entries, just make the `key` function return a tuple containing the values you wish to sort on in order of importance.  For example:

```
c2.sort(key = lambda row: (row[2],row[1]))
```

or:

```
c2.sort(key = lambda row: (row[2],row[1],row[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with itemgetter?

`lst.sort(key=lambda l: list(reversed(l))` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In Python2, you can use this

```
>>> lst = [['John',3],['Blake',4],['Ted',3]]
>>> lst.sort(key=sorted)
>>> lst
[['John', 3], ['Ted', 3], ['Blake', 4]]
```

This works because ints are always "less than" strings in Python2

You can no longer sort `str` and `int` objects in Python3 though