# Sorting two lists -- one is a list of lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays. One is N by M the other is N by 1. I want to be able to sort the first list by any one of it's M dimensions, and I want the lists to keep the same order (i.e. if I swap rows 1 and 15 of list1, I want rows 1 and 15 of list2 to swap too.)

For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,6],[3,4],[2,5]])
b = np.array([[.5],[.8],[.2]])
```

Then, I'd like to be able to sort by, say, the first element of each row in `a` to give:

```
a = [[1,6],[2,5],[3,4]]
b = [[.5],[.2],[.8]]
```

or to sort by, say, the second element of each row in `a` to give:

```
a = [[3,4],[2,5],[1,6]]
b = [[.8],[.2],[.5]
```

I see lots of similar problems in which both lists are single dimensional like, e.g, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764298/is-it-possible-to-sort-two-listswhich-reference-each-other-in-the-exact-same-w). Or questions about sorting lists of lists, e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398589/sorting-a-list-of-lists-in-python). But I can't find what I'm looking for.

Eventually I got this to work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,6],[3,4],[2,5]])
b = np.array([[.5],[.8],[.2]])
package = zip(a,b)
print package[0][1]
sortedpackage= sorted(package, key=lambda dim: dim[0][1])
d,e = zip(*sortedpackage)
print d
print e
```

Now this produces d and e as I want:

```
  d = [[3,4],[2,5],[1,6]]
  e = [[.8],[.2],[.5]
```

But I don't understand why.  The  `print package[0][1]` gives 0.5  -- which is not the element I'm sorting by. Why is this?  Is what I'm doing robust?

Comment: Why are you zipping your numpy arrays and sorting them in Python in the first place, instead of just doing this all in numpy? It'll be easier to think through (and a whole lot faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `print package[0][1]` returns `0.5` is because it is accessing the numbers in your list of tuples "as a whole" whereas `sorted` is looking at each individual element of the given iterable.

You zip `a` and `b` in `package`:

```
[([1, 6], [0.5]),
 ([3, 4], [0.8]),
 ([2, 5], [0.2])]
```

It is at this point that you `print package[0][1]`. The first element is obtained with `package[0]` = `([1, 6], [0.5])`. The next index `[1]` gives you the *second element* of the *first tuple*, thus you get `0.5`.

Considering `sorted`, the function is examining the elements of the iterable, *individually*. It may first look at `([1, 6], [0.5])`, then `([3, 4], [0.8])`, and so on.

So when you specify a key with a `lambda` function you are really saying, for this particular element of the iterable, get the value at `[0][1]`. That is, sort by the second value of of the first element of the given tuple (the second value of `a`).

Answer (score 2):

To apply the same sort order to several numpy arrays, you could use [`np.argsort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). For example, to sort by the second column:

```
indices = a[:,1].argsort()
print(a[indices])
print(b[indices])
```

Output:

```
[[3 4]
 [2 5]
 [1 6]]

[[ 0.8]
 [ 0.2]
 [ 0.5]]
```

Comment: Follow up question: This works great within the same function, but what about if I want to pass this sorted numpy array to another function? The function, written by someone else (and that I shouldn't muck with), is only expecting to have the ordered array passed to it

Comment: @BenBlumer: `a[indices]` returns such ordered array. Just pass it as is.

Comment: Great.  That makes this all the more useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

inside your `package`:

`package[0]` is `(a[0], b[0])`
thus, `package[0][1]` is b[0].

your package is triple-nested. `key=lambda dim : dim[0][1]` means you use `item[0][1]` as a key to sort `package`. `package` consists of `item`, and `item` is is double-nested.

to see what element you're sorting by, use `package[x][0][1]` x being index of that item