# Is there a way to find the highest value in a multi-dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

`monthlyAVG = [["January",6,3],["Februrary",7,3],["March",10,4],["April",13,6],["May",17,9],["June",20,12],["July",22,14],["August",21,14],["September",19,12],["October",14,9],["November",10,6],["December",7,3]]`

I have the above code as a set list of values. Is there a way to find the highest and lowest numerical values from the list? I'm new to python so any answers would be appreciated!

I'm hoping to output the highest value and lowest value along with the month name so that it looks something like this:

```
January 3
July 22
```

Comment: Your question can be confusing please show us the expected output from your example.

Comment: Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398589/sorting-a-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: what about February 3? in case of equality what do you want?

Comment: The first occurrence is fine for what I need it for, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for them with a for loop through your array:

```
# Init values to first month
max_value = monthlyAVG[0][1]
min_value = monthlyAVG[0][2]
max_month = min_month = monthlyAVG[0][0]

# Check the other values in the array to find and update the searched
for month in monthlyAVG[1:]:
  if month[1] > max_value:
    max_value = month[1]
    max_month = month[0]

  if month[2] < min_value:
    min_value = month[1]
    min_month = month[0]

print('{} {}'.format(min_month, min_value))
print('{} {}'.format(max_month, max_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
monthlyAVG = [["January",6,3],["Februrary",7,3],["March",10,4],["April",13,6],["May",17,9],["June",20,12],["July",22,14],["August",21,14],["September",19,12],["October",14,9],["November",10,6],["December",7,3]]
check_num_list = [i[1:] for i in monthlyAVG]
print(max(map(max, check_num_list)))
```

That will print "22" being the largest number in the list. I do a list comprehension when creating `check_num_list` by only grabbing all elements in each sublist that isn't in index 0 (so only numbers) then I use map to find all the largest numbers in each sublist and then pass max one more time against it to find the largest number of the remaining numbers in `print(max(map(max, check_num_list)))`

Comment: Ok thanks. Can I reverse this to work with minimum as well? Would I just replace the 'max' with 'min'? And can it have the month printed next to it?

Comment: You could also just do: `'{0} {2}'.format(*min(monthlyAVG, key=lambda L: L[1]))`